Dividing months in ways beside 旬間
I know that there is a method of dividing the month in Japanese into 旬: 上旬、中旬、下旬. However, I also could've sworn that there was at least one, even two other ways to divide the month into sections. I believe they don't use the same prefixes (上、中、下), though they might; possibly 最 or 後 or 初. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.


Perhaps you've seen 初旬? It refers to the first 5-10 days of a month: Difference between 上旬 and 初旬
You can use 月の前半 or 月の後半, too, although this method is not specific to months.

